# Putting axis category labels on stacked barplot in r

Tags: r, axis-labels

I am trying to create a bar graph where the category labels appear on a stacked bargraph.

I have a graph that so far looks like this.

```
Captivate<-c(17, 35, 42, 7)
Challenge<-c(39,44,17,0)
Clarify<-c(6,33,56,6)
Confer<- c(11,33,50,6)


df<-t(rbind(Captivate, Challenge, Clarify, Confer))
par(mar=c(6, 6, 4, 2) + 0.1)
barplot(df, horiz=T, space=.1, axes=FALSE)
```

Each section of the bars corresponds to the percentage of people in a category. What I want to do is put the category labels at the top of the graph. The category labels are "Always", "Most of the Time", "Some of the Time", "Never".

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you done any searching? The must be other answers already on SO. Admittedly they will mostly put the labels on the default bottom position (=1) but `axis` has a side argument and just change 1 to 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 axis(3, at= c(10, 30, 70, 95) , 
  labels=c("Always", "Most of the Time", "Some of\n the Time", "Never"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As DWin posted, you need to use the `axis` function after your call to `barplot`.

If you want further understanding, [this page](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/) outlines how to customise plots generated through R:
[Quick R: Advanced Graphs](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/)

The relevant information for axis modification is found [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html):

[Modifying Axes and Text](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html)